# Keyboard appears but quickly disappears in react-native application using Galaxy S9

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, keyboard, galaxy

Using Galaxy S9/S8, when android botton navbar is hide, when click on TextInput, the keyboard quickly disappear and I can't type, if I pin the botton navbar the problem doesn't happens anymore.

This is a video example:
http://gustavoandrade.net/tella/video.mp4

This is Android Studio output when click on TextInput to show keyboard:

```
01-10 15:36:35.121 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
01-10 15:36:35.152 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
01-10 15:36:35.193 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/InputMethodManager: SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 19422 view : com.gentilapp
01-10 15:36:35.195 19422-19422/com.gentilapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@e85ff7e nm : com.gentilapp ic=com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactEditTextInputConnectionWrapper@c5a5cdf
01-10 15:36:35.195 19422-19422/com.gentilapp I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
01-10 15:36:35.246 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=1
01-10 15:36:35.267 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 3505223680} changed=false
01-10 15:36:35.285 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 1253) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 1253) or=1
01-10 15:36:35.301 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 3505223680} changed=false
01-10 15:36:35.342 19422-19501/com.gentilapp I/ReactNativeJS: 'Token para Fila', null
01-10 15:36:35.354 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 19422
01-10 15:36:35.390 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) or=1
01-10 15:36:35.412 19422-19422/com.gentilapp D/ViewRootImpl@6784d38[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 3505223680} changed=false
```

#### UPDATE

Fixed, the problem was Drawer component of native-base.

Comment: Can you share your code part where is the text input, seems to me it has something to do with some event triggered automatically.

Comment: I has this issue with a custom keyboard, the fix , at least for me was setting the fixed height of the textinput (i had it with flex:1)

Comment: @vitomadio it is just a TextInput in a basic empty component with a View.

Answer (score 0):

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" //under AndroidManifist.xml